# Atlantis plan erroring with querying Cloud Storage failed message

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, systemd, google-iam, atlantis

I have a GCP VM to which a GCP Service Account has been attached.

This SA has the appropriate permissions to perform some `terraform` / `terragrunt` related actions, such as querying the backend configuration GCS bucket etc.

So, when I log in to the VM (to which I have already transferred my terraform configuration files, I can for example do

```
$ terragrunt plan

Initializing the backend...

Successfully configured the backend "gcs"! Terraform will automatically
use this backend unless the backend configuration changes.

Initializing provider plugins...
- terraform.io/builtin/terraform is built in to Terraform
- Finding hashicorp/random versions matching "3.1.0"...
- Finding hashicorp/template versions matching "2.2.0"...
- Finding hashicorp/local versions matching "2.1.0"...
.
.
.
```

(...and the plan goes on)

I have now set up [`atlantis`](https://www.runatlantis.io/) to run as a `systemd` service (under a same name user)

The problem is that when I create a PR, the plan (as posted as a PR comment) fails as follows:

```
Initializing the backend...

Successfully configured the backend "gcs"! Terraform will automatically
use this backend unless the backend configuration changes.

Failed to get existing workspaces: querying Cloud Storage failed: storage: bucket doesn't exist
```

Does anyone know (suspects) whether this problem may be related to the change the terraform service account is / can not be used by the systemd service running `atlantis`? (cause the bucket is there, since I am able to plan manually)

**update**: I have validated that a `systemd` service **does** inherit the GCP SA by creating a systemd service that just runs this script

```
#!/bin/bash

gcloud auth list
```

and this does output the SA of the VM.

So I changed my original question since this apparently is not the issue.

Comment: Can you please run the following command? 
`terraform init -reconfigure`

Answer (score 0):

Posting my comment as an answer for visibility to other community members.

You were maybe getting an error because there can be an issue with the terraform configuration. To update it, Please run the following command and see if it solves your issue.

```
terraform init -reconfigure
```